# Typeerror 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

i want to print my 2nd key (Sally) but i keep getting the error!!!

```
ages = {"Demi":12, "Sally":15, "Micheala":22, "Joseph":19}
print(ages)

x = ages.keys()
print(x[2])
```

Comment: Yes, the `.keys()` of a dict is a `dict_keys` object, which doesn't support indexing like that. The thing is that, conceptually, dicts *do not have an order*, so asking for the "2nd" key *doesn't make sense*. (As it happens, the current implementation does maintain order internally, but that still doesn't help us here).

Comment: You need to convert the `dict_keys` object to a list: `list(ages.keys())`. However, @KarlKnechtel is correct to point out that this is not a good practice. If you want order, use an ordered container like a list or tuple.

Comment: Or `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: okay, understood...Thanks